# How to call javasscript_tag in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed the each step of above question and here are my changes:

```
In show.html.erb (http://localhost:3000/posts/24)

<% javascript_tag do %>
 $(function() {
   setInterval(function(){ $.get("/posts/<%= @post.id   %>");   }, 5000);
    });
<% end %>

<span id="changed_data">
 It should be change after every 5 seconds
</span>
```

## controller class

```
def show
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js
   format.html
 end
```

end

## Added a new file

```
app/views/posts/show.js.erb
$("#changed_data").html("<h2> Changed </h2>");
```

But it sounds like that `javascript_tag` is not calling `jquery` method. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% javascript_tag do %>
 $(function() {
 setInterval(function(){ $.get("/posts/<%= @post.id   %>");   }, 5000);
 });
<% end %>
```

change to

```
<script>
 $(function() {
 setInterval(function(){ $.get("/posts/<%= @post.id   %>");   }, 5000);
 });
</script>
```

It should work.